# NLog files do not get propagated into a Azure blob storage (Azure SDK 7.1)

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, nlog, diagnostics

I have configured my Azure Web Role to periodically copy NLog logs to an Azure blob storage. Using Azure SDK 2.7.1 
I have setup NLog to archieve into archieve folder of Local Storage and configured the directory monitoring to copy the file to the blob. I have tried it in both emulator and actual deployment, but don't get any file copied into the blob. Not sure what am I doing wrong. Here is my configuration snippets:

NLog.config:

```
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" lineEnding="Default" autoFlush="true" concurrentWrites="true" 
        fileName="${environment:variable=NLOGDIR}\server_${date:format=yyyyMMdd-hh}.log"
        archiveFileName="${environment:variable=NLOGDIR}\archive\server_${date:format=yyyyMMdd-hh}_{#####}.log" archiveEvery="Minute" archiveNumbering="Sequence" maxArchiveFiles="720">
```

ServiceDefinition.csdef:

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
<Runtime>
  <Environment>
    <Variable name="NLOGDIR">
      <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/CurrentInstance/LocalResources/LocalResource[@name='LogStorage']/@path" />
    </Variable>
  </Environment>
</Runtime>
<LocalResources>
  <LocalStorage name="LogStorage" cleanOnRoleRecycle="true" sizeInMB="4096" />
</LocalResources>
```

diagnostics.wadcfgx:

```
  <DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration overallQuotaInMB="4096">
    <DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Error" />
    <Directories scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
      <IISLogs containerName="wad-iis-logfiles" />
      <FailedRequestLogs containerName="wad-iis-failedreqlogfiles" />
      <DataSources>
        <DirectoryConfiguration containerName="server-logs">
          <LocalResource relativePath=".\archive" name="LogStorage" />
        </DirectoryConfiguration>
      </DataSources>
    </Directories>
    <PerformanceCounters scheduledTransferPeriod="PT30M">
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\Available MBytes" sampleRate="PT3M" />
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Web Service(_Total)\ISAPI Extension Requests/sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Web Service(_Total)\Bytes Total/Sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET Applications(__Total__)\Requests/Sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET Applications(__Total__)\Errors Total/Sec" sampleRate="PT3M" />
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Requests Queued" sampleRate="PT3M" />
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\ASP.NET\Requests Rejected" sampleRate="PT3M" />
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" sampleRate="PT3M" />
    </PerformanceCounters>
    <WindowsEventLog scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
      <DataSource name="Application!*" />
    </WindowsEventLog>
    <CrashDumps>
      <CrashDumpConfiguration processName="WaIISHost.exe" />
      <CrashDumpConfiguration processName="WaWorkerHost.exe" />
      <CrashDumpConfiguration processName="w3wp.exe" />
    </CrashDumps>
    <Logs scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M" scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Error" />
  </DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration>
```

Not sure where is the disconnect. Lots of very recent articles still refer to .wadcfg files, even though in 2.7.1 it's depreciated.

Will appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: I used to have this problem when we upgraded our solution from 2.4 to 2.6. Please check the diagnostics infrastructure logs for IO errors related to the directory where NLog files are stored. Let us know if you see anything there.